# Apply a single decorator to multiple functions

Tags: python, decorator

I've searched for this, but the results I've seen involve the opposite: applying multiple decorators to a single function.

I'd like to simplify this pattern.  Is there a way to apply this single decorator to multiple functions?  If not, how can I rewrite the above to be less repetitious?

```
from mock import patch

@patch('somelongmodulename.somelongmodulefunction')
def test_a(patched):
    pass  # test one behavior using the above function

@patch('somelongmodulename.somelongmodulefunction')
def test_b(patched):
    pass  # test another behavior

@patch('somelongmodulename.somelongmodulefunction')
def test_c(patched):
    pass  # test a third behavior
```

```
from mock import patch

patched_name = 'somelongmodulename.somelongmodulefunction'

@patch(patched_name)
def test_a(patched):
    pass  # test one behavior using the above function

@patch(patched_name)
def test_b(patched):
    pass  # test another behavior

@patch(patched_name)
def test_c(patched):
    pass  # test a third behavior
```

Comment: What's the issue? Your example code should work just fine, and it's as pythonic as it can be. There's no "simpler" way to apply a decorator to three functions other than applying it to three functions.

Comment: I disagree - there is a simpler way. @justhecuke presented an answer that works in principle, and I tested a variation that worked. You can get a list of the function names you want from globals() and assign the decorated functions back to them. It could make a lot of sense if you have a long list of unit tests and you want to apply the same mock to each of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make the "long" function call only once and decorate all three functions with the result, just do exactly that.

```
my_patch = patch('somelongmodulename.somelongmodulefunction')

@my_patch
def test_a(patched):
    pass

@my_patch
def test_b(patched):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get fancy, you can modify `globals()`.  The general idea below should work.

```
test_pattern = re.compile(r'test_\w+')
test_names = [name for name in globals().keys() if test_pattern.match(name)]
for name in test_names:
  globals()[name] = decorate(globals()[name])
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on what justhecuke said about using globals(), in case the function is located in a different module, you could do something like this:

```
import inspect

def decorator_func(func):
    def inner():
        print("Decorated")
        func()
    return inner

moduleA = __import__('moduleA')
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(moduleA):
    if name.startswith('test_') and inspect.isfunction(obj): #Conditions to apply decorators on expected functions
          moduleA.__dict__[name] = decorator_func(moduleA.__dict__[name])
```